# What the best way to minimize appstore costs for a free app that saves lives?

Tags: iphone

So I have an idea for a free app which can reduce IV related hospital errors and save lives.  There's no source of income for me from the app (I'd even remain anonymous, no self-promotion of any kind).  What's the cheapest way for me to get this on appstore?  Am I stuck paying $99/yr. because if I am I won't do it (I'm not made of money) and there will be no improvement to IV related errors and no improvement to related hospital deaths.

Comment: Consider getting donations.. there are a lot of projects that uses that.. You can use an iOS developer friend that already paid the 99$... And you can create an open source project, It can get a boost from the community and donations too if you'll like

Comment: "You can use an iOS developer friend that already paid the 99$..." ... I like that idea the best, problem is I don't have any iOS developer friends.  Anything else involving me having a developer account would involve annual fundraising, and really nothing's free so eventually I'm sure I'd be paying for it one way or another.

Comment: What about open source it? And you'll ask one of the contributors to upload to App Store or get a donation for the project

Comment: That is a darn good idea Yitzchak.  I still think it might be a hard sell because I did talk to a couple developers and the feedback was they didn't want to get sued if there was any health care risk.  It's not a big thing for me, because that's what it means to be an entrepreneur especially in doing the "right thing", but I find that a lot of programmers are really wussies when it comes to the risk part of entrepreneurism.

Comment: You just need to write a user agreement and you're covered

Comment: By the way, Android is much cheaper

Comment: Yitchak - thanks, I suspected so about the user agreement.  Most health professionals use iPhones.  iPhone has a similar app, but it's like around $20 and overly complicated and the UI isn't great.